# Sqlite: get the values of the error fields

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to build a report for displaying the unmatched fields by comparing two tables and their values in the following format.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

| UserID | UserName | Year | Error Field | TableAValue | TableBValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER01 | Roy | 2017 | City not a match | London | Paris |
| USER02 | Peter | 2005 | Username not a match | Peter | Roma |
| USER02 | Peter | 2005 | Course not a match | Science | Humanities |

This is a partial working code. I it shows the error fields correctly. But I also want to show the values in the TableAValue and the TableBValue.

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (
   SELECT a.userid, a.username, a.year, CASE column1
        WHEN 1 THEN IIF((a.username != b.username), 'Username not a match', NULL)
        WHEN 2 THEN IIF((a.city != b.city), 'City not a match', NULL)
        WHEN 3 THEN IIF((a.course != b.course), 'Course not a match', NULL)
        WHEN 4 THEN IIF((a.speciality != b.speciality), 'Speciality not a match', NULL)
   END [Error Field]
  FROM tableA a INNER JOIN tableB on (a.userid = b.userid and a.year = b.year)
   cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4)) n
 ) q
WHERE [Error Field] IS NOT NULL
```

**Output of the above code:**

| UserID | UserName | Year | Error Field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER01 | Roy | 2017 | City not a match |
| USER02 | Peter | 2005 | Username not a match |
| USER02 | Peter | 2005 | Course not a match |

How can I display the Values from TableA and TableB as shown in the above expected output table?

Comment: "*But I also want to show the values in the TableAValue and the TableBValue.*" - It's not clear what you're looking for. Show sample input tables and expected output explicitly.

Comment: Additionally, what's the point of cross-joining with 1, 2, 3, 4 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account your comment, this is a new approach:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT a.userid, a.username, a.year, 
    CASE column1
        WHEN 1 THEN IIF((a.username != b.username), 'Username not a match', NULL)
        WHEN 2 THEN IIF((a.city != b.city), 'City not a match', NULL)
        WHEN 3 THEN IIF((a.course != b.course), 'Course not a match', NULL)
        WHEN 4 THEN IIF((a.speciality != b.speciality), 'Speciality not a match', NULL)
    END [Error Field],
    CASE column1
        WHEN 1 THEN IIF((a.username != b.username), a.username)
        WHEN 2 THEN IIF((a.city != b.city), a.city, NULL)
        WHEN 3 THEN IIF((a.course != b.course), a.course, NULL)
        WHEN 4 THEN IIF((a.speciality != b.speciality), a.speciality, NULL)
    END TableAValue,
    CASE column1
        WHEN 1 THEN IIF((a.username != b.username), b.username)
        WHEN 2 THEN IIF((a.city != b.city), b.city, NULL)
        WHEN 3 THEN IIF((a.course != b.course), b.course, NULL)
        WHEN 4 THEN IIF((a.speciality != b.speciality), b.speciality, NULL)
    END TableBValue
FROM tableA a INNER JOIN tableB on (a.userid = b.userid and a.year = b.year)
cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4)) n
) q
WHERE [Error Field] IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concat `||` operator for that:

```
        WHEN 1 THEN IIF((a.username != b.username), 'Username not a match:' || a.username || '<>' || b.username, NULL)
        WHEN 2 THEN IIF((a.city != b.city), 'City not a match:' || a.city || '<>' || b.city, NULL)
        WHEN 3 THEN IIF((a.course != b.course), 'Course not a match:' || a.course || '<>' || b.course, NULL)
        WHEN 4 THEN IIF((a.speciality != b.speciality), 'Speciality not a match:' || a.speciality || '<>' || b.speciality, NULL)
```

Reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Comment: Thanks @Santilín.  Using a concat operator will not present the value in separate cells like in the output table above.

Comment: Then you should repeat the CASE WHEN clause twice and output the value from TableA and TableB